# TextEditor multi-line display on website losing newlines

Tags: swift, swiftui, text-editor

[image]When i save data entered from a TextEditor on my IOS app and then preview that text on website version it doesn't display the newline and consider the whole description as a single line text.

- my qustion is : **how to display the same description with multiline on the website exactly as shown on the the iphone app using TextEditor ?**

Answer (score 0):

after some Research i've found this solution :

```
let descriptionInputHtmlForm = descriptionInput(of: "\n", with: "<br>", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

Before sending the entered input to the Database we do some modifications by replacing the **\n** with **br inside <>** in this way the html will detect new line break